# Dice game add a payment method

Tags: python, random, dice

I have this code and I want to add a payment method to make the person start with 6$. Each time the dice roll if they are equal you add the sum of the dice to the guy's money;  if they are not equal you subtract 2.

```
import random
a = random.randrange(1 , 6)
b = random.randrange(1 , 6)
print (a , b)
if a == b:
    print("you win" , 2 + a + b)
else:
    print("you lose")
```

Trial code that almost worked but is highly stupid:

```
import random
a = random.randint(1 , 2)
b = random.randint(1 , 2)
print (a , b)
e = 1
g = 1
for x in range(g):
    e = 6
    g = e/2
    if a == b:
        print("you win")
        e = a + b + e 
        
    else:
        print("you lose" )
        e = e - 2
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first declare the money in the account. You do a loop for 10 trials, you can change the loop for whatever you like (`while True:` or something similar).

For every loop, you give your two dices a random number. Then, you check if the numbers are equals `if diceA == diceB:`.
If this condition is `True`, you add to that person money the sum of dice A and dice B.
If the condition is not `True`, then the program to the `else:` statement. We remove 2 from the personMoney.

```py
import random

personMoney = 6

for i in range(10):
    diceA = random.randint(1, 6)
    diceB = random.randint(1, 6)
    if diceA == diceB:
        personMoney += diceA + diceB
    else:
        personMoney -= 2
    print(personMoney)
```

Comment: its a great code thx just needed few alterations
import random

'personMoney = 6

for i in range(10):
    diceA = random.randrange(1 , 6)
    diceB = random.randrange(1 , 6)
    print(diceA , diceB)
    if diceA == diceB:
        print("you win")
        personMoney += diceA + diceB
    else:
        print("you lose")
        personMoney -= 2
    print(personMoney)
    if personMoney == 0:
        break
input("press ENTER to exit")'

Comment: oof i dont know how to make a code comment

Comment: You can read more about formatting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

So, first you need to declare a variable that would represent player's money amount. Then, I assume you'd like to have a while loop so the variable would persist its state between throws. And this loop would break, for example, when the player becomes a bankrupt, i.e. money amount becomes equal to zero. And the code would look like this.

```
import random

money = 6
while money != 0:
    a = random.randint(1 , 6)
    b = random.randint(1 , 6)
    if a == b:
        money += a + b
    else:
        money -= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to form something along the lines of:

```py
import random

start = 6
play = True
while play:
    print(f"You have {start}")

    dice_a = random.randint(1,6)
    dice_b = random.randint(1,6)

    print(f"Dice 1 = {dice_a} Dice 2 = {dice_b}")

    if dice_a == dice_b:
        start += dice_a + dice_b
        print(f"You win! you now have {start}")
    else:
        start-=2
        print(f"You lose! you now have {start}")
    i = input("Play again? If yes press any key except N. If not press N")

    if i == "N" or i =="n":
        print(f"You finished with {start}")
        play=False
```

You could keep adding more conditions depending on whether the money is out or more etc.